# /testfor values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In MCPE/Bedrock, the commands sort of appear as you type them, giving you options to choose from. I typed in `/testfor @p[r=3,` and then, these appeared:

1. C
2. Dx
3. Dy
4. L
5. Lm
6. M
7. Name
8. R
9. Rm
10. Rx
11. Rxm
12. Ry
13. Rym
14. Type
15. X
16. Y
17. Z

What do all these different values mean? I know about `Type` and `Name`, so you don't need to list those when answering this question.

Also, slightly off-topic but I am looking to create a testfor command that activates a comparator when there is a player with a certain item in their hand. Is there one of these tags that would help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `x/y/z` - Change the starting point for area selections. They do nothing on their own, but change where `r`, `rm`, and `dx/dy/dz` start from.
- `r` - The maximum **r**adius around the starting point for entity selection. Only entities within the radius will be selected.
- `rm` - The minimum **r**adius. Only entities outside the minimum radius will be selected.
- `dx/dy/dz` - Define a bounding box for entity selection. The box starts at the starting point, and extends `dx/dy/dz` + 1 blocks in the respective directions. If any of them are negative, it instead extends `dx/dy/dz` - 1 blocks in that direction. If you use any of them, the ones you leave out are assumed to be `0`.
- `c` - The maximum **c**ount of entities that will be selected. The closest entities are chosen first. If you make this negative, it will select the furthest entities instead.
- `l` - The maximum XP **l**evel of target players.
- `lm` - The minimum XP **l**evel.
- `m` - The game**m**ode of target players.
- `rx/ry` - The maximum rotation of the target entity around the X and Y axes.
- `rxm/rym` - The minimum rotation.

> I am looking to create a testfor command that activates a comparator when there is a player with a certain item in their hand.

I don't think this can be done in BE. It would require access to player data, or a command that can check whether a slot contains a certain item, and BE has neither.